# Qt design stylesheets major disfunctionality

Tags: c++, css, qt, user-interface

Currently I am trying to deal with C++ using Qt 5.6.3 via Qt Creator with built-in designer. Stylesheets are applied in a very weird way.

My idea of creating a Qt application is:

1. use build-in designer to edit automatically created `*.ui` files, so that the whole design would be more demonstrative than using only code;
2. use a separate stylesheet file `*.qss`, so that all CSS code would be placed together;
3. use `QObject::setObjectName()` for each `QWidget` in each designed window's or dialog's constructor, so that changing stylesheet for each it's widget would be done instantly and would not demand `*.ui` file contents change.

All this is supposed to provide another kind of abstraction layer for widgets. Suppose there is some custom `FirstDialog` with `ui->okButton` and `ui->cancelButton`. Suppose there is also some custom `SecondDialog`, with `ui->retryButton` and `ui->cancelButton`. Suppose we want to change stylesheets in a flexible way, so that OK button would have one color, retry button would have another color, and both cancel buttons in both these dialogs would have third color.

Then I would make it so:

```
FirstDialog::FirstDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
    QDialog(parent, Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint),
    ui(new Ui::FirstDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->okButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MyButtonOk"));
    ui->cancelButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MyButtonCancel"));
}
```

and:

```
SecondDialog::SecondDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
    QDialog(parent, Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint),
    ui(new Ui::SecondDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->retryButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MyButtonRetry"));
    ui->cancelButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MyButtonCancel"));
}
```

with stylesheet file:

```
QPushButton#MyButtonOk {
    background-color: green;
}
QPushButton#MyButtonRetry {
    background-color: yellow;
}
QPushButton#MyButtonCancel {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And now the issue itself. Naturally, my application is really pretty large. It has two very similar dialogs, and stylesheets are **sometimes** (in some widgets, to be more precise) applied instantly, and **sometimes** not. For example, one of these two similar dialogs works fine enough as is, while the other one does not... Despite widget types (`QPushButton`, `QLabel`,...) do correspond and object names are actually changed, I have to do some extra work, and I cannot figure out why. My guess, the dialog itself does not really matter, but time of it's construction does. For example, I have to do so:

```
SecondDialog::SecondDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
    QDialog(parent, Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint),
    ui(new Ui::SecondDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->retryButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MyButtonRetry"));
    ui->cancelButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MyButtonCancel"));
    // Changes:
    ui->cancelButton->ensurePolished(); // surprisingly does not help
    ui->cancelButton->style()->unpolish(ui->cancelButton); // helps
    ui->cancelButton->style()->polish(ui->cancelButton); // helps
}
```

It would be helpful to hear from the more professional Qt designers, why stylesheets are applied so unpredictably. Is there any way to make it more stable and reliable? What does it all depend of? Are there any signals needed to be forcibly processed?

Thanks in advance! Hope, it all is clear enough...